# How implement 'undo' object editing without storing actual object in Redux store?

Tags: javascript, react-redux, undo

Our React/Redux app uses a javascript 3D library (three.js) and allows editing of objects within that library.

We have thus far avoided coupling the app to three.js by abstracting an asset layer and enforcing controller access of a Object3D repo rather than storing Object3D's in the Redux store.

But now we are looking at implementing the 'undo/redo' feature. It is looking like, in order to use Redux to implement Undo (using, for eg. redux-undo), it will be necessary to violate our encapsulation and simply place three.js objects in the store in order to make undo work (last 'past' state replacing the 'present' state).

Only other way I can think of is to store the view model of the object in the Redux store, and have an observer listening for changes to the view model, in which case the object would be rolled back/reset. This will be a lot of extra processing though, since the observer will be poked every time any Redux state changes (unless the observer is a React component).

Is there any other way of doing this without rolling our own abstract commands and history lists?

Our current flow uses thunk middleware:

```
function updateObjectProperty(id, path, value) {
  return function( dispatch, getState, controllers) {
    try {
      controllers.assetController.updateAsset(id, path, value)
      .then ( () => {
        ...
        dispatch( updateObject(id, etc) )
        .then ( () => {
           //do other stuff
        });
     } catch(error) {
         dispatch( failObjectUpdate( etc );
     }
   };
  }
```

Comment: I guess the problem here is the imperative nature of your controller? you're making calls like "modify an object in this way" vs describing actions and responding to them. I think you could still make this work if your controller was observing stuff rather than being called directly kind of like how you mention. are you able to share any code? would make it easier to write an answer. right now it's a little too general since a number of different solutions could be made to work

Comment: @azium our flow is to use thunk action creators, in which our controller is called (possibly async call) and then regular action dispatching is chained onto that.